# Owl Carousel with Laravel cacheing issue

Tags: laravel, owl-carousel

I am working in a Laravel Application. Here I am using Owl Carousel. My code for Owl Carousel is like below

```
$('#reccomended').owlCarousel({
        center: true,
        items: 2,
        loop: true,
        margin: 0,
        responsive: {
            0: {
                items: 1
            },
            600: {
                items: 2
            },
            767: {
                items: 2
            },
            1000: {
                items: 3
            },
            1400: {
                items: 4
            }
        }
    });
```

I am supplying data to Owl Carousel from database. I deleted all data from Database but Owl carousel still displaying data.

What is the solution ?

Comment: Did you clear application/browser cache.That might resolve your issue.

Comment: The view must have been saved in cache, remember you are using JavaScript so the browsers save them files in cache. Try clearing cache

Comment: @Flash, browser cache ? I am using incognito Window.

Comment: @zlatan, I am using incognito Window.

Comment: Yes buddy. Clear the browser cache

Comment: @Flash, I am using incognito window and clear browser cache and delete all data from database table, but I am seeing Carousel.

Comment: ```Ctrl + Shift + Del``` and clear some cache from your browser